# Get the section of each heading on heading:section pair in dict

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x

I have a text file like this:

```
APPENDIX -- GLOSSARY
-------------------------------------------------------------------

  Asymmetrical Encryption:
      Encryption using a pair of keys--the first encrypts a

  Big-O Notation, Complexity:
      Big-O notation is a way of describing the governing.

      In noting complexity orders, constants and multipliers are
      conventionally omitted, leaving only the dominant factor.
      Compexities one often sees are:

      #*------------- Common Big-O Complexities ---------------#
      O(1)              constant

  Birthday Paradox:
      The name "birthday paradox" comes from the fact--surprising

  Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC32):
      See Hash.  Based on mod 2 polynomial operations, CRC32 produces a
      32-bit "fingerprint" of a set of data.

  Idempotent Function:
      The property that applying a function to its return value
      'G=lambda x:F(F(F(...F(x)...)))'.
```

I want to parse the text file to have output like:

```
{'Asymmetrical Encryption': Encryption using a pair of keys--the first encrypts a, 
'Big-O Notation, Complexity':'Big-O notation is a way of describing the governing. In noting complexity orders, constants and multipliers are conventionally omitted, leaving only the dominant factor. Compexities one often sees are: #*------------- Common Big-O Complexities ---------------# O(1)              constant}', ..so on }
```

This is what I have done:

```
 dic = {}
    with open('appendix.txt', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        lines = data.split(':\n\n')
        for line in lines:
            res = line.split(':\n      ')
            field = res[0]
            val = res[1:]

            dic[field] = val
```

This is messing up with `:` values in the text despite the header. The output is not correct.

Comment: Unless you already know the field names, you are going to have a tough time doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are parsing the text based on the first spaces you can use a script like this:

```
class spaceParser(object):
    result = {}
    last_title = ""
    last_content = ""

    def process_content(self, content_line):
        if self.last_title:
            self.last_content = self.last_content + content_line.strip()
            self.result[self.last_title] = self.last_content

    def process_title(self, content_line):
        self.last_title = content_line.strip()
        self.last_content = ""

    def parse(self, raw_file):
        for line in raw_file:
            #look for patterns based in tabulation
            if line[0:4] == "    ":
                #content type
                self.process_content(line)
            elif line[0:2] == "  ":
                #title type
                self.process_title(line)
            else:
                #other types
                pass
        #append the last one
        self.process_content("")

parser = spaceParser()
with open('appendix.txt', 'r') as raw_file:
    parser.parse(raw_file)

print parser.result
```

Comment: -1 for use of `global` and because you never call `close` on `raw_file`. (almost) ALWAYS use `with` syntax when dealing with files.